# Is the "byte" type in messages signed or unsigned?

Tags: moveit, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that [moveit_msgs/CollisionObject](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/CollisionObject.html) uses the type `byte` which isn't discussed in the documentation for message types found at http://wiki.ros.org/msg .  Is this an alias for uint8, int8, or some form of message structure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201858/is-the-%22byte%22-type-in-messages-signed-or-unsigned?/) by [johnw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2548/johnw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [ros/msg - Message Description Specification - 2.1 Fields - 2.1.1 Field Types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Field_Types):

> [..]
>
> Deprecated:
>
> char: deprecated alias for uint8
>     byte: **deprecated alias for int8**

So it is indeed an alias.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2